# Black borders with external monitor on MBA 2013

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, dvi

I have a problem that I'm not able to fix. I'm getting black borders, some king of margin. The display doesn't use the full space in the monitor. I have a total of four monitors in my house and three TVs. I only get this problem with one monitor.

Note that I don't have this problem with my Mac Mini with the exact same monitor... only with my Macbook Air. I tried to plug the monitor with TB->DVI and with TB->HDMI. Same problem. I tried to switch cable. Same problem. I have a DIAMOND USB 2.0 DVI ADAPTER, and when I use it, I don't get any black border.

I have no "overscan" setting in the System Preferences.

My monitor is a I-INC iH282. There is no settings in the menu to adjust overscan or something like that.

Any idea why it does that? I spent my two last evening trying to find a solution on Google.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Black border problem]

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?  I have the same problem: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154917/30-monitor-has-black-border-around-desktop